# How Disallow a mirror site (on sub-domain) using robots.txt?

Tags: seo, cdn, robots.txt

I have a website saying :

```
http://domain.com/
```

mirror site on

```
http://cdn.domain.com/
```

I don't want `cdn` to be indexed. How can I write `robots.txt` rule to avoid the `cdn` from being indexed without disturbing my present `robots.txt` excludes.

My present `robots.txt` excludes :

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /abc.php
```

How can I avoid `cdn.domain.com` from being indexed ?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /abc.php
```

Comment: `Try this`: I guess you could put a seperate robots.txt file inside the sub-domain and do your exclusions from there. You can block an entire subdomain via robots.txt, however you'll need to create a robots.txt file and place it in the root of the subdomain, then add the code to direct the bots to stay away from the entire subdomain's content. `User-agent: *` - `Disallow: /`

Comment: Consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904642/disallow-or-noindex-on-subdomain-with-robots-txt

Comment: you could make a robots-cdn.txt and indescriminately rewrite robots.txt to that from the subdomain's virtural host.

Comment: Can-not have different `robots.txt` since its a cdn and can-not have different codebase.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that ... I'm suggesting an additional robots file called robots-cdn.txt that will, by the magic of rewriting be served up on the cdn instead of the robots.txt

Comment: Now it boils down to `what have you tried?`.

Comment: It's basically the non-accepted answer on the question that @Fred referenced

Comment: @Orangepill I'm almost afraid to `post it as an answer` lol! We don't know what the OP tried, or hasn't tried.

Comment: @Fred go for it ... you found docs... I was guessing :)

Comment: @Orangepill Going for it. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Orangepill. Guys thanks for a great effort. All those who mis-understood the questions voted it down.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in your root .htaccess file add the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Amazon.CloudFront$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-cdn.txt
```

And then create a separate robots-cdn.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

When accessed through via http://cdn.domain.com/robots.txt will return the contents of the robots-cdn.txt file... otherwise the rewrite won't kick in and the true robots.txt will kick in.

This way you are free to mirror the entire site (including the .htaccess) file with the expected behavior

Update :

- `HTTP_USER_AGENT` did it since Amazon uses it while querying it from any location.
- I have verified and it works

Comment: Sir, I don't think this will work. Since cdn is not a machine and hence if I ask robots from cdn, it will inturn ask it from domain.com as a normal browser client. So, we will get the same robots.txt (that we don't want)

Comment: http_host variable isn't referring to a network host. its referring to the host portion of a url. you can view the same variable in php an the $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] superglobal

Comment: You were right, although `HTTP_USER_AGENT` worked instead for `amazon`. I have made the required changes in the answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the codebase are the same, you can generate your `robots.txt` dynamically and change its content depending on the requested (sub)domain.

Comment: Hm.. can you help with some code, since I also tried to attempt what you said.

Comment: What language and platform are you using?